# How to animate root controller without effecting the children node animation with respect to world?

Tags: maya

In Maya, I have an animation of a human character in which he is taking a step to its right and then turning 180 degrees, but the problem is that the root of the object is not animating and is still.

Whereas in the animation the feet of the character are moving to right and taking the character away from its root.

What I want to do is animate the root of the object without changing the position of other nodes with respect to world,

So In then end the animation is supposed to look exactly the way it is looking now but the root of the character also needs to move with the character.

**The Long Solution**

One Way to do this is to duplicate the character as D and on the original one i animate the the root of the character whichever way I want and then keeping the duplicated model as a reference to the animation, I re animate the original character

**Read below if you want to know what I tried. and what definately wont work**

Another way i tried was to deparent all children then shift the root and then reparent the children back, but this only works for which ever frame I was at, rest of the animation gets spoilt.

**How actual solution might work-**

Basically is there a way by which I can make all the animation fixed in the world coordinates and automatically adjust their local position and rotation the remain fixed in respect the world until I animate the root.

Comment: I made an attempt but that attempt failed and was definately not the way to do it hence dint mention, and you will not find anything remotly close to what i want to do over the internet, which i have already searched, that was the reason of asking this. If you still want me to add what i attempted i will edit my question. also there is a straight forward way to do it but that is not what i am after as its labour intensive approach and not really a better approach

Comment: You can achieve this through script, but do you need to preserve animation curves or can they be keyed each frame?

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like the root is the top node of your rig that you would use for initial placement of the character within a scene... if that's correct, and you want to move it but have all of the other controls seem like they're in the same parent space as the root control while actually moving with the root, you'll have to counter animate them in some way...

If you can change the hierarchy of your scene, re-parent those controls in the same parent space as the root control, so you would actually be moving all of the controls together (although you would not be able to rotate from that root and affect the character in the same way).

If you have a way of giving the controls a space switch, you could put them in the global space with that...

You could also possibly have some other nodes outside of the character's hierarchy that you animate and then parent constrain the other controls to those nodes.

It might be difficult just about any way you go about it because of the animation curves on that root node which could cause the other controls to move in a 'floaty' behavior unless you add a bunch of keys to lock them back down again.... but even then...